# Passport Expires March 31 2020 - Going to Italy

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, passports, international-travel, us-citizens

I have two questions.

Would you be stopped if you went to Italy today as an American with a passport that expires March 31, 2020?

Also, if you got your passport ten years ago and have since then been married and thus have a different surname than the one on your passport. Is this a problem?

Thank you

Comment: According to https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/before-you-go/travelers-with-special-considerations/schengen.html, you generally need your passport to be valid for six months after your date of entry into the foreign country, so if you're traveling before the end of September you should be fine.

Comment: Provided the name on your flight booking matches your previous name as shown in your passport :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Italy is part of the Schengen Area. For short stays (not exceeding 90 days in total during any 180-day period), the whole 26-state area is treated as a single country as regards passport validity, maximum visa-free stay and passport stamps.

Your passport must remain valid for at least three months beyond the end of your proposed stay. If only planning a very short visit, a little more than three months left would be fine; for the maximal 90 days of visa free stay, you would need about six months. You have more than that left on your passport.

If all relevant documents match, most importantly booking/tickets and passport, it should not matter whether you use your present or your former name. Otherwise you should carry some sort of proof of your name change.